# Как покрасить только номера списка на CSS?

Tags: html, css-selectors

Я хочу покрасить только номера пунктов, но краситься все через CSS, подскажите пожалуйста оператор.

```css
li {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainbox">
  <ol class="list">
    <li>Text#1</li>
    <li>Text#2</li>
    <li>Text#3</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для выделения маркеров списков ввели новый псевдоэлемент - `::marker`:

```css
li {
  color: orange;
}

li::marker {
  color: red;
  font: bold 24px 'Mistral', cursive;
}

li:hover::marker {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainbox">
  <ol class="list">
    <li>Text#1</li>
    <li>Text#2</li>
    <li>Text#3</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Перед использованием, [убедитесь](https://caniuse.com/css-marker-pseudo), что нужные браузеры уже поддерживают этот псевдоэлемент.

---

```css
.mainbox { display: flex; }

li {
  color: orange;
}

.boom li::marker { color: red; font: bold 12px 'Courier', monospace; }
.list li::marker { color: green; font: bold 24px 'Mistral', cursive; }
.yeah li::marker { color: violet; font: bold 28px 'Arial', sans-serif; }

.boom li:hover::marker { color: black; }
.list li:hover::marker { color: blue; }
.yeah li:hover::marker { color: yellow; }
```

```html
<div class="mainbox">
  <ol class="boom">
    <li>Text#1</li>
    <li>Text#2</li>
    <li>Text#3</li>
  </ol>
  <ol class="list">
    <li>Text#1</li>
    <li>Text#2</li>
    <li>Text#3</li>
  </ol>
  <ol class="yeah">
    <li>Text#1</li>
    <li>Text#2</li>
    <li>Text#3</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, а как сделать так, чтобы это распространялось только на 1 класс, а не на все?

Comment: @mksmptrnk: подробнее изложите, не пойму чего-то...

Comment: Данный код работает для всех <li>, а можно сделать так, чтобы это работало только для класса "list"?

Comment: @mksmptrnk: просто укажите нужный класс. Добавил пример.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь разобрался:)

Answer (score 4):

Если разметку нельзя менять, то можно использовать [counter-increment](http://htmlbook.ru/css/counter-increment) на псевдоэлементе, который можно стилизовать как угодно

```css
ol {
    list-style: none;
    counter-reset: i;
}

ol li {
    counter-increment: i;
}

ol li:before {
    content: counter(i) ".";
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainbox">
  <ol class="list">
    <li>Text#1</li>
    <li>Text#2</li>
    <li>Text#3</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

```css
ol {
    list-style: none;
    counter-reset: i;
}

ol li {
    counter-increment: i;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

ol li:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

ol li:before {
    content: counter(i) ".";
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: red;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
li {
  color: orange;
}

li span {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainbox">
  <ol class="list">
    <li><span>Text#1</span></li>
    <li><span>Text#2</span></li>
    <li><span>Text#3</span></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```